# How to verify that dialog is shown in flutter test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

When my widget is pressed I show datePicker like this:

```
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  firstDate: DateTime(1900),
  initialDate: selectedDate,
  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
),
```

I'd like to test if it is shown on tap event like this:

```
testWidgets('CustomDateWidget ', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(testWidget);
  await tester.tap(find.byType(DateTimeField));
  expect(find.byType(CalendarDatePicker), findsOneWidget);
});
```

But it is failed with

Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree

Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "CalendarDatePicker" (ignoring offstage
widgets)>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to pump widget after tap `await tester.pump();`